# How to override deactive method in Router?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to override `deactive` method on Router with the following:

export class AnimationRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
    publicRoutes: any;
    private parentRouter: Router;

```
constructor(_elementRef: ElementRef, _loader: DynamicComponentLoader,
            _parentRouter: Router, @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string) {
    super(_elementRef, _loader, _parentRouter, nameAttr);

    this.parentRouter = _parentRouter;
}

deactivate(instruction: ComponentInstruction){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log("deactivvated state");
        return super.deactivate(instruction);
    },1000);
}

activate(instruction: ComponentInstruction) {
    console.log(instruction);
    return super.activate(instruction);
}
```

}

As you can see, I am trying to create delay in changing webpage - so that I can create some animations.

However, using this, I have TypeScript compiler error:

> : error TS2415: Class 'AnimationRouterOutlet' incorrectly extends base
>   class 'RouterOutlet'.   Types of property 'deactivate' are
>   incompatible.
>       Type '(instruction: ComponentInstruction) => void' is not assignable to type '(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction) =>
>   Promise'.
>         Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Promise'.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the return type of an overridden function that way. The return type needs to be the same type as the return type in the super class or a more specialized one.

If you implement [CanDeactivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanDeactivate-interface.html) you can a promise where the router waits for before it routes away from the component.

Comment: thanks! should I override the original Router 'deactivate' to add a delay?

Comment: `routerOnDeactivate()` is to be added to the component and supports waiting for a promise to settle by default. There might be other, more generic ways, but I didn't dive that deep into routing myself yet.

Comment: `routerCanDeactivate()` can be a better choice here, maybe. It waits before unloading the view.

Comment: @A_Singh that was my first thought but the docs to `routerCanDeactivate` don't mention a `Promise` while the docs to `routerOnDeactivate` explicitely state that it ways for a returned `Promise` to settle.

Comment: I think that it also returns a Promise [see at the end here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-beta.12/modules/angular2/src/router/interfaces.ts#L99-L124)

Comment: @A_Singh great, thanks a lot! The doc is not up-to-date. I'll create an issue.