# How to delay router deactivation in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I have been playing with the Angular2 Router, to figure out some other [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232714/route-change-transition-effect).

I've came across something like that in Angular2 documentation:

> deactivate(instruction: Instruction) : Promise 
>   Removes the
>   contents of this router's outlet and all descendant outlets

I am wondering how can I set delay, and use new class as a provider, so that all of the Router navigation has some delay (lets say 1s). I want to do it, so that I can have slide in slide out animation - If I would be able to delay Route deactivation, I can have both Routes (previous and next) visible at one time.

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234352/how-to-override-deactive-method-in-router/36234378#36234378

Answer (score 2):

You can implement [CanDeactivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanDeactivate-interface.html) but this is required on each component that is added/remove by the router. If you return a `Promise` that settles after 1s then the removal of the component is delayed this 1s.

I don't know if there is a more generic way like using a custom implementation (subclass) of the `<router-outlet>` or similar.

Comment: I was playing with it, and it doesn't activate another state. I will provide plnkr soon.

Comment: There is a related open issues (couldn't find it just yet). There is also work in progress for better animations support https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/6768